# How to edit style attribute on Angular six component

Tags: attributes, styles, angular6

I'm new to Angular development.

I have started developing a web site using Angular 6 Material (material.angular.io) and kicked this off with navigation schematic that delivers a responsive toolbar and side nav component for navigation.  The default HTML layout looks something like this:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav"
    ...
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
     ...
    </mat-toolbar>

    <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink='/menu1'>menu 1</a>
        ...
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content >
    <mat-toolbar color="primary" >
        <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-toolbar" >
          <mat-toolbar-row >  
            ...
          </mat-toolbar-row>
        </mat-toolbar> 
    </mat-toolbar>
    <!-- Application components go here-->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
  </mat-sidenav-content>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

mat-sidenav-container contains the 'drawer' mat-sidenav to the left of mat-sidenav-content

I want to programmaticaly shrink the width of mat-sidenav, subsequently shifting mat-sidenav-content to the left. 
I can do the first part, by using [ngClass] on mat-sidenav and changing this on demand -

However, I'm not having the same success with the content section on the right of the drawer, by just merely changing its CSS Class to have the correct width..

Looking at the source code, I see mat-sidenav-content not only has CSS Classes but also has style attribute as "margin-left:200px"
(which overrides any CSS class styling I set)

I want to programmaticaly change this margin-left value.

How do I do that ?

Thanks -

Comment: Have you try to do this in your component.css? .mat-sidenav-content{margin-left:100px !important;}

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
        <mat-sidenav #drawer [(ngStyle)]="{'width': myWidth}">
```

typescript:

```
       export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
           myWidth: 25px;

        }
```

Comment: Thanks - the syntax in the html file [(...)] raises an issue: Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 25 in [{'margin-left': myWidth}=$event]   is this correct ?